# How to call a Sub Statement that contains keypress validations from a Module to Windows form?

Tags: vb.net, module, keypress

I have this Sub Statement on my Module that contains character restriction from a keypress event.

```
  Public Sub keyFilter(ByRef e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs)
          If Not ((Asc(e.KeyChar) >= 48 And Asc(e.KeyChar) <= 57) Or
            (Asc(e.KeyChar) >= 65 And Asc(e.KeyChar) <= 90) Or
            (Asc(e.KeyChar) >= 97 And Asc(e.KeyChar) <= 122) Or
            Asc(e.KeyChar) = 8 Or
            Asc(e.KeyChar) = 127 Or
            Asc(e.KeyChar) = 95 Or
            Asc(e.KeyChar) = 32) Then
                e.KeyChar = ChrW(0)
                e.Handled = False
          End If
End Sub
```

I want to call the Sub statement above to windows form keypress event by using this code but this produces an error. It says ,`Value of type 'Char' cannot be converted to 'System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs`

```
Private Sub txtTableName_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtTableName.KeyPress

    Call keyFilter(e.KeyChar)

End Sub
```

Can you tell me what is/are the problem with my codes? Is it really possible to call a keypress event function in windows form?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to change this line :

```
Call keyFilter(e.KeyChar)
```

to this :

```
Call keyFilter(e)
```

`KeyFilter` expect `KeyPressEventArgs` as parameter, but you passed `e.KeyChar` which is a `Char`. You should pass `e` which is `KeyPressEventArgs` instead.

Answer (score 2):

`KeyFilter()` function takes an argument of type `KeyPressEventArgs`, you should replace the calling statement with `Call keyFilter(e)`, do not pass e.KeyChar..

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
Public Sub keyFilter(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs)
  If Not ((Asc(e.KeyChar) >= 48 And Asc(e.KeyChar) <= 57) Or
    (Asc(e.KeyChar) >= 65 And Asc(e.KeyChar) <= 90) Or
    (Asc(e.KeyChar) >= 97 And Asc(e.KeyChar) <= 122) Or
    Asc(e.KeyChar) = 8 Or
    Asc(e.KeyChar) = 127 Or
    Asc(e.KeyChar) = 95 Or
        Asc(e.KeyChar) = 32) Then
        e.KeyChar = ChrW(0)
        e.Handled = False
  End If
End Sub 

Private Sub txtTableName_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtTableName.KeyPress
    Call keyFilter(sender, e)
End Sub
```